# Contents inside an iframe don't load at all or a warning shows up - iframe src is unsecured and different domain that the containing page

Tags: javascript, security, dom, iframe, cross-browser

I have a webpage from https://creator.zoho.com that contains an iframe. The iframe scr is http://somedomain.example.com (NOTE that it is not https). The iframe content contains scripts for JQuery, SignalR etc.

I get the following behavior across OS and browsers with their default security settings:

**Windows**

1. Internet Explorer - No issues, works fine.
2. Chrome - Does not load the iframe context at all (I see the DOM of iframe and it is empty). A shield icon appears on the right of the address bar and on click the message is "the page includes scripts from unauthenticated sources." I have an option "Load unsafe script". I click it and everything is works.
3. Firefox - Does not load anything in the iframe. No security indicator nor any warnings.
4. Safari - No issues, works fine.

**Mac OS**

1. Chrome - Does not load the iframe context at all (I see the DOM of iframe and it is empty). A shield icon appears on the right of the address bar and on click the message is "the page includes scripts from unauthenticated sources." I have an option "Load unsafe script". I click it and everything is works.
2. Firefox - Does not load the iframe context at all (I see the DOM of iframe and it is empty). A shield icon appears on the **left** of the address bar and on click the there is a security related message. I have an option "Load unsafe script". I click it and everything is works.
3. Safari - Does not load the iframe context at all. No security warning. No indication that something is blocked.

Does anyone have a clue as to what is wrong?

After a good amount of Googling, I can came across - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options - but not very sure if this is a solution for my case for all browsers OR if it is even the right solution for any browser for the situation that I am facing.

Thanks in advance for reading my post.

Comment: For security reasons, you can't mix HTTP and HTTPS.  Different browsers enforce that differently.

Comment: For security reasons..

Comment: Any idea why chrome says "Unauthenticated" instead of "Unsecure" in the message?

Comment: @SLaks so according to you, if the iframe contents was loading from an SSL enabled location (https), they this issue will be solved?

Comment: @MoizTankiwala: Exactly.  Unauthenticated means that you have no proof that the remote server is who you think it is. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIA_triad#Authenticity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was resolved by moving the application (that was loading in the iframe) to HTTPS. So now the parent page and the iframe both are on HTTPS. They still on different domains, but both being HTTPS solved the issue for me.